# Registry Editor DWORD32 to not view extensions

Tags: browser

I want to create a way that on Microsoft edge I can block the ability to turn off certain extensions. I have website blocker extensions but unfortunately you can just disable them. Does anyone know of a way to use registry editor and then under the file 'edge' to create a DWORD32 that would disable the ability to turn off the extension or not be able to see the extensions? If I cannot do those but I could not see all extensions that would work too but some extensions I still want easy access too. Note: I do not want to disable the extension in any way, just to not be able to see or manipulate it.

I have not tried making up my own DWORD32 as I do not want to corrupt my computer by doing something incorrectly.